# Show value of one column, if the value of another column is greater than of two other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new here and I'm struggling with a problem in Python: on how to show value of one column, if the value of another column is greater than of two other columns.

This is quite abstract, so of course please see the below:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"Choice 1": [0.8, 1.0, 0.2], "Choice 2": [0.4, 0.2, 0.6],"Choice 3": [0.2, 0.4, 0.8],  "Rating 1": [8, 0, 2], "Rating 2":[0, 2, 4], "Rating 3":[0, 8, 5]})
>>> df
   Choice 1  Choice 2 Choice 3 Rating 1  Rating 2  Rating 3  
0  0.8       0.4         0.2        8         0         0
1  1.0       0.2         0.4        0         2         8
2  0.2       0.6         0.8        2         4         5
```

The output that I'm looking for is that:
if the value of Rating 1 > Rating 2 OR Rating 3, it should return a corresponding value of Choice 1.

If Rating 2 > Rating 1 OR Rating 3, it should return the value of Choice 2.

Same thing with Rating 3 > Rating 1 OR Rating 2, the value returned would be Choice 3.

So, the first argument would show:

```
  Choice 1   
0  0.8
```

And for the second row:

```
  Choice 3   
1  0.4
```

I would be very grateful for your help!

Comment: So is the result going to be a new column within the df?

Comment: Thanks for the question! No, I would like to avoid having a new column. What I wanted to achieve as output  is the name of the choice column, and its value at the row given the condition. I really hope it's possible :)

Comment: now that I think about this abit more, how will you handle the event of having two or more ratings with the same values?

Comment: Hi Manakin! Luckily in my df I don't have an input like this, but I guess the best option would then be for it to just print 'Equal rating found' or skip

Answer (score 3):

You can use [advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing), or equivalently numpy's [`np.take_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html) to index the choices according to the ratings:

```
import numpy as np

choices = df.filter(like='Choice').to_numpy()
ratings = df.filter(like='Rating').to_numpy()
np.take_along_axis(choices, ratings.argmax(1)[:,None], axis=1).squeeze()
#array([0.8, 0.4, 0.8])
```

If you want the corresponding column names:

```
choice_cols = df.filter(like='Choice').columns
choice_cols[ratings.argmax(1)]
# Index(['Choice 1', 'Choice 3', 'Choice 3'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Thank you very much yatu! Would it be possible for it to include a name of the "Choice" column somehow? I tried writing a function to do this but  I can't make it work...

Comment: Sure, its simpler, you need to index the column names directly, updated @ZuzannaOrłowska

Comment: Thanks yatu! I'll go try it now